# How can I run rake with --trace within capistrano?

Tags: ruby, rake, capistrano

I want capistrano to invoke rake with --trace so I can figure out why it's failing. How do I do this? `set :rake 'rake --trace'` doesn't work.

Comment: When you say "doesn't work", what happens?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The best way I found is:

```
set :rake, "#{rake} --trace"
```

This way you don't overwrite the *rake* variable.

For example if you use *bundler* this is set before to:

`"bundle exec rake"`

and after to:

`"bundle exec rake --trace"`

Answer (score 1):

The chances are your custom tasks aren't using the `rake` variables, but instead hard-coding rake, here's an example:

```
run("rake sass:compile")
```

This is hard-coded, and won't care about your setting `set :rake, 'rake --trace'`, here's the correct way:

```
run("#{fetch(:rake)} sass:compile")
```

Or, shorthand:

```
run("#{rake} sass:compile")
```

You can see this in practice in the Capistrano source code, in the one place that the default recipes actually invoke `rake`, in the migrations task: https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/master/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy.rb#L387

Comment: oddly, migrations is where my deploy was failing and wehre i wanted to turn on --trace, so i guess that should have worked...